# Buscar posição do array a partir de um determinado termo sem usar a função 'inArray'

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Em um determinado método, do meu input, ao escrever "me" ele verifica se a fruta existe neste array:

```
['banana', 'melao', 'uva', 'melancia']
```

No caso, me traz (posição 1 - melao e posição 3 - melancia).

Tentei usando o `inArray`, mas ele só observa a palavra completa e não só parte da string dela...

PS: NÃO posso usar `jquery UI` por motivos técnicos, pois daria conflito com a função `autocomplete`.

Comment: Não percebi bem o que procuras, se puderes clarear a pergunta seria ótimo. Mas de modo geral podes fazer algo tipo `arr.filter(el => { return el.indexOf(letras) != -1; });`. Se explicares melhor o que queres fazer posso dar um exemplo.

Comment: De uma olhada no [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/x8on1u92/) e me fale se te ajuda, é um exemplo sem o uso do jQuery. Havia postei uma resposta mais removi pois não sei se entendi sua pergunta hehe :)

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta, como assim inArray só retorna a palavra inteira? O inArray retorna a posição do item na array e não a palavra. Claramente que se usar a posição do index retornada na array vai retornar por exemplo `"uva"`. Afinal você quer retornar uma fruta ou quer dividir as palavras em cada item do array, posta como fez pra entendermos o problema.

Comment: Opa, valeu pelas respostas.

é que quero escrever b e ja aparecer banana, o inarray só acha se eu escrever a palavra completa.

@Brunno era isso ae! Só precisei de uns ajustes.

Valeu!

Comment: @caiocafardo que bom que te ajudou, desfiz a exclusão da resposta :)

Comment: Tem como colocar a função completa pra gente te ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer usando `RegExp` sem precisar do jQuery:

```
var fruits = ['banana', 'melao', 'uva', 'melancia'];

function matchFruit(input) {
  var reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
  return fruits.filter(function(fruit) {
    if (fruit.match(reg)) {
      return fruit;
    }
  });
}

function changeInput(val) {
  var matchResult = matchFruit(val);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = matchResult;
}
```

Segue [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/x8on1u92/).

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer utilizando a underscore.js vide exemplo abaixo:

```js
var array   = ['ABC', 'ABCD', 'ABCDE'];
var search  = "ABCD";
var results = _.filter(array, function(value) {
  return value.indexOf(search) != -1;
});

alert(results.join(' | '));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Infelizmente não posso usar nada externo a não ser jquery....